# Can I just use <img> tag src and alt to serve WebP files vs using <picture>?

Tags: php, html, css, asp.net, webp

I'm in the process of converting images in my website to WebP image format. If the system is unable to serve the file, it will use the PNG version. I specify both WebP and PNG format in the 'src' and 'alt' element of 'img' as follow:

```
<img class="d-flex d-lg-flex" 
 src="/assets/img/bytebixlogo.png.webp?h=757c7b444ce465289d079f63b22bbca0" 
 alt="/assets/img/bytebixlogo.png?h=82cf7689d1dee6b6948666e42d5e364d">
```

But in some websites, i see the following complex implementation:

```
<picture>
    <source data-lazy-srcset="https://openplant.b-cdn.net/wp-content/webp-express/webp-images/doc- 
        root/wp-content/uploads/OpenPlantLogo_TransparentBG.png.webp" type="image/webp" 
        srcset="https://openplant.b-cdn.net/wp-content/webp-express/webp-images/doc-root/wp- 
        content/uploads/OpenPlantLogo_TransparentBG.png.webp">
    <img id="image-4125-897" alt="" src="https://openplant.b-cdn.net/wp 
        content/uploads/OpenPlantLogo_TransparentBG.png" class="ct-image webpexpress-processed lazyloaded" data-lazy-src="https://openplant.b-cdn.net/wp- 
        content/uploads/OpenPlantLogo_TransparentBG.png" data-was-processed="true">
    <noscript>
    <img id="image-4125-897" alt="" src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%20viewBox='0%200%200%200'%3E%3C/svg%3E" class="ct-image op-logo-image animated fadeInUp webpexpress-processed" data-lazy-src="https://openplant.b-cdn.net/wp-content/uploads/OpenPlantLogo_TransparentBG.png">
    </noscript>
</picture>
```

Is there something i'm missing?
And why is this complex implmentation of WebP is used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `alt` attribute in `<img>` tag is for an alternative **text** to show to browser when the image is not available. You can take a look at the description here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#Attributes

So, putting an image path in the `alt` attribute won't get you what you want. When the PNG image is not available, browsers will simply display the path as plain text.

The `<picture>` tag is to solve the shortcomings of `alt` so you can have another image as a fallback. You can have multiple fallback / situational replacement with it. Since it is designed to be much more powerful and versatile, the syntax looks more complicated.

With more power, comes more responsibilities :-)

More details about `<picture>` tag: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture